# .DBML file and LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity

In my DBML file I have mapped some tables and stored procedures, and the stored procedures return type is ISingleResult . T is some mapped table. But I want to take the data into my own created entities rather than LINQ to SQL created entites. The entites created by me are also the same as the mapped table entities and their use lies when we send data across the a web service. So , how can I proceed by creating a wrapper around the DBML file so that I always get data in my own created entites.

Comment: I'm not clear if you want to bring the results of your stored procs into your own entities or whether you are just looking to create your own entities that are mapped to the DBMS tables, can you clarify?

Comment: I just want to capture data in my own entites which are not mapped to the tables but the attributes are the same as that of the table columns

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is designed for this scenario, but if you cannot move to that for other reasons, [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) is worth looking into.

You can add attributes to linq to sql entities that are not mapped to database columns, by adding a property in the designer and leaving the datasource property empty.